# Forecasting daily online visits in r

Tags: r, forecasting

We have three years of data for online visits at a daily level. We want to forecast the daily visits for the next 90 days. What would be the best method to capture weekday seasonality , holiday seasons, and also the drift.

Can this be successfully done in R? We are currently using R. We have considered ARIMA but it does not capture seasonality.

While converting the data to a time series in R, what should be the "frequency"?

Should we use ARIMA with regressors?